# Unable to find the source of error dialogflow fulfillment

Tags: dialogflow-es, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

I am trying to create intent in which when the user sends a parameter, then it should be checked in the database that is already there or not. If it already exists user gets a response A and if not it is added to the database, & the user gets response B. I am using Axios to make the API calls. But the code is not working.

I am getting a following errors in the console.

```
TypeError: Cannot set property 'response' of undefined
at axios.get.then.response (/srv/index.js:33:18)
at <anonymous>
at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:229:7)"
```

Show matching entries
Hide matching entries
Add field to summary line

I am not a professional, I am doing all this coding by learning from online tutorials and youtube videos Please help.

```
function idHandler(agent) {
const idcard = agent.parameters.idcard;
const idvalue = ' ';
const idname= ' ';
axios.get('API' + idcard)
    .then(response => {
        this.response = response.data;
        idvalue = this.response[0].IDcard;
        idname = this.response[0].Name;
    }); 
    
if (idcard === idvalue) {
    const ans = 'Name of ' + idname + ' is already present in the List';
    agent.add(ans);
} else {
    const data = [{
        idcard: idcard
    }];
    axios.post('API', data);
}
```

}

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow? You indicated that there is an error - can you update the question to include the error that you're getting? Or what happens when you try to test this handler. The more information you can provide, the better our chances are of being able to help you. See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

You have a few issues with both how to code for Dialogflow, and how to express some of the syntax correctly. Some of that is because it looks like you're mixing code that expects Promises with code that doesn't.

The axios library is meant to work with Promises - the `get` and `post` methods both return Promises. So you can either work with them by using an `await` method, or by using the `.then()` method that the returned Promise has. You may want to look up details of both.

Additionally, Dialogflow requires that you either return the Promise, or that your handler be an `async` function (which will return a Promise for you).

If you're using the `.then()` approach, however, then *everything* you do that relies on the call to axios *must* be done inside the `.then()` block and you must return that Promise. If you use `await`, then your function *must* be declared as an `async` function. (You can probably mix the two - but don't.)

So that part of your code might look something like:

```
  return axios.get( url )
    .then( response => {
      // Do EVERYTHING in here
    });
```

And inside the `then()` code block is where you would extract the values you want, call `agent.add()` with the message, and possibly make the API call to add data.

While this didn't get flagged as an error, you are trying to assign a value to a `const` after it is initially set. This is an error. Those should probably be declared using `let` instead.

Your error *looks* like it is saying that `this` is undefined. Which seems... odd.  But also not really an issue since you probably don't need to be using `this` for most of what you're trying to do. If you scope the variables with `let`, then they should be available for the life of the function.